# Skeleton CSS - responsive form

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I have a form implemented using skeleton css.  I was using a three column (i.e. one-third columns) layout but this resulted in a lot of white space because of the respective lengths of the columns content. I would prefer a horizontal layout similar to the following:

**Textbox1       Textbox2      Textbox3**

**Textbox4       Textbox5      Textbox6**

Which then collapses for mobile as so:

**Textbox1**

**Textbox2**

**Textbox3**

**Textbox4**

**Textbox5**

**Textbox6**

The only way I have thought I can do this so far is to wrap each textbox in it's own 'one-third' column.  Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set class to your text boxes (or `input[type="text"]`) and CSS:

For desktop:

```
.yourclass {
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
 }
```

For mobile:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    .yourclass {
         width: 100%;
         float: left;
    }
}
```

This: https://mislav.net/2010/04/targeted-css/ may be helpful.

Comment: Ok and do this within a sixteen column I presume?

Comment: You may use child selector, too - if your textboxes are in `.somediv`, you may use `.somediv > input`

Comment: width 33% then carries over though so they don't stack for a mobile screen - would media queries be needed for this to set a width of 100%?

Comment: I edited the comment, I've forgotten to copypaste everything, sorry

Comment: Thanks - I'll do it with media queries.  I was just hoping to do it through classes but media queries will suffice.  Thanks